Mathematical induction, is it really a proof of truth?
This soft question is, I think, borderline mathematical philosophy.
One of my former professors used to say that induction does not prove that a statement is true, but it merely eliminates the possibility of existence of any finite counterexample. For instance, when we prove the typical example that the sum of the first $n$ positive integers is $n(n+1)/2$, we are not "proving" the formula is true for all positive $n$, but rather we assert that it is impossible to find a finite $n$ for which the formula claimed fails to work.
One may say that they are exactly the same thing, but I've always felt that there is a subtle difference between showing something is true and showing something is not false. I just am curious if this is a somewhat of a shared belief in the mathematical society, or an isolated idiosyncrasy of mine. Any resources, insights, or opinions are all welcome.

If you believe in the law of the excluded middle, then "not false" or "no counterexample" is the same as "true"! I think many novice mathematicians are uncomfortable with induction for the same reason as you, but this discomfort tends to go away with experience.

I don't really understand your professor's comment. I see induction as positively proving every instance of a formula $P(n)$. It gives you an algorithm to write down a complete proof for any $n$. For example, if you want to know that $P(10)$ is true, you can follow the chain of implications $P(0)\Rightarrow P(1)\Rightarrow\cdots\Rightarrow P(10)$.

Either your instructor didn't understand induction or you didn't understand your instructor. The inductive step proves that if a proposition is true for $n=k$, then it is true for $n=k+1$. Combine that with the base case and we get that it is true for $n=1,n=2,n=3,n=4\dots$ ad infinitum.

The point is that all positive integers are finite.  Once you've excluded the possibility of a finite counterexample, you've shown that the statement is true.

True is equivalent to not false as along as we have the excluded middle, i.e. $A\lor\lnot A$ is always true. For an example where they are not the same, take a look at intutionistic logic.

Maybe your professor was deriving induction from the well-ordering principle. In that case one does consider the minimum possible counterexample, so I can see it.

First of all: induction literally says "it is true", not "there is no counterexample". Secondly "true" is equivalent to "not false". "True for all" is equivalent to "there is no counterexample". There is no subtle difference between them, not in mathematics.

@JohnDouma this has nothing to do with excluded middle. The formula $\forall_x P(x)$ is simply equivalent to $\neg\exists_x\neg P(x)$ in the first order logic. Mathematical induction is not related to excluded middle at all. It doesn't claim that something is true. It claims something is true if certain conditions are met.

@freakish The comment about the excluded middle was meant to address his concern that there may be a difference between not false and true. It seemed to me that the lack of the excluded middle was what he was thinking about in his last paragraph.

@JohnDouma there is no difference. And again, it has nothing to do with excluded middle. Which states that at least one of $A$ and $\neg A$ is true. But that is unrelated to the fact that "not false" and "true" are the same thing. Which is still true, even when we don't assume excluded middle, or assume something else.

Perhaps by "difference between not false and true" you were thinking about some third option, different from true/false. But that requires some different, multi-valued logic. And most certainly does not relate to the classical mathematical induction. Which might not even be meaningfully expressable in such logic.

@freakish Yes, that is my point exactly. It seems that user134070 was leaning toward that idea in his last paragraph.

There are two common definitions of the natural numbers. The base axioms are $PA^-$, i.e. Peano Arithmetic without induction, which assert that the natural numbers are a discrete ordered commutative semiring. Then there are two ways to proceed. We either add the Well-Ordering Principle or The Principle of Mathematical Induction.
The point is that these two axioms are equivalent, at least over classical logic. A typical proof that the Well-Ordering Principle implies the Principle of Mathematical Induction goes as follows: Suppose that for some proposition $P$ we have $P(0)$ and that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ for all natural numbers $n$. Let $S$ be the set of all counter-examples of $P$, i.e. $S$ consists of all natural numbers $n$ such that $P(n)$ is false. If $S = \emptyset$, then $P$ has no counterexamples, so $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers $n$ by the Law of the Excluded Middle, as desired. Otherwise, $S$ is nonempty, thus $S$ has a least element, call it $n_0$, invoking the Well-Ordering Principle. Since $P(0)$ is true, thus $n_0 > 0$. Since $n_0$ is the least element, so $n_0 - 1 \notin S$, i.e. $n_0 - 1$ is not a counterexample to $P$, meaning that $P(n_0 - 1)$ is not false. Thus, by the Law of the Excluded Middle, $P(n_0 - 1)$ is true. Hence $P((n_0 - 1) +1) = P(n_0) $ is true, so that $n_0 \notin S$, a contradiction. QED.
In brief, the Well-Ordering Principle implies the Principle of Mathematical Induction since, if there is any counterexample at all, then there must be a least counterexample. Since the base case holds, this least counterexample is strictly positive. But then the induction step implies that the predecessor of this counterexample is also a counterexample, contradicting the original counterexample being least. This proof fleshes out what your professor might have meant.
Yet you see that in the above proof, at various points I used the Law of the Excluded Middle, which could be formulated as saying that "any proposition that is not false has to be true". This logical law explicates what perhaps was the subtle difference you felt.
So one way to formulate your question precisely is:

Over intuitionistic logic, without the Law of the Excluded Middle, is the Well-Ordering Principle equivalent to the Principle of Mathematical Induction over $PA^-$?

In the above, we used second-order formulations of the Well-Ordering Principle and the Principle of Mathematical Induction. There are also first-order formulations. Assume the Law of the Excluded Middle for the rest of the discussion, so that having no counterexample is equivalent to a proposition holding true for all natural numbers. In first-order Peano Arithmetic, that is $PA^-$ together with a first-order axiom schema for induction, there are nonstandard models of arithmetic. In these models, there are nonstandard natural numbers that are strictly larger than any standard natural number. In particular, $0$ is not a finite predecessor of any nonstandard natural number, so that these nonstandard natural numbers may be considered as "infinite". As these nonstandard models of arithmetic also satisfy the induction schema, thus induction does not merely eliminate any finite counterexample: **induction eliminates all counterexamples, finite or "infinite" **.
Finally, the proposition that every natural number is finite, in the sense $\forall n, n = SS\cdots S0$ is not a first-order arithmetic statement. Here $S$ denotes successor. Assuming the base case and the induction step, showing that, say $P(5)=P(SSSSS0)$ is true can be done in $PA^-$ without the induction schema, and also without the Law of The Excluded Middle. For any fixed finite number of $S$'s, you can deduce that $P(S\cdots S0) $ holds from the base case and the induction step without induction. But showing that $\forall n, P(n) $ requires induction.

The answer to the question you formulate is negative: Well-ordering is not equivalent to Induction over Intuitionistic Logic. Work in a structure that satisfies $PA^-$ and Induction. Take any proposition $P$ and consider the predicate $p(x)$ defined as $(P\wedge x=0) \vee (\neg P \wedge x=1)$. Clearly $\neg \forall x. \neg p(x)$. But if there is a least element $x$ such that $p(x)$, then induction allows you to prove $x=0\vee x \neq 0$, and by a case analysis on this disjunction you get $P\vee \neg P$. Since $P$ was arbitrary, you get that if Well-ordering is satisified, so is Excluded Middle.

in other words, without Excluded Middle, induction does not imply the Well-Ordering Principle?

That's right. Accordingly, in the common varieties of constructive mathematics, $\mathbb{N}$ is assumed to satisfy Induction, and not Well-ordering.

may I ask about the converse : in constructive math, does the Well-Ordering Principle imply induction?

I don't know whether well-ordering implies induction over $PA^-$ in first-order intuitionistic logic. I suspect the answer will be negative, with some countermodel that lacks decidable equality (since the implication holds iff WO implies LEM iff WO implies decidable equality over that theory). But it's worth asking this as its own separate question on the site.

thanks for sharing, ZAK. I think I might ask this converse on Math Overflow. Thanks for pointing out that one implication does not hold.


One of my former professors used to say that induction does not prove that a statement is true

Mathematical induction doesn't prove anything. It's marely an implication, a formula. Regardless, the conclusion is that something is true, yes. That's the most popular variant, by a wide margin.

but it merely eliminates the possibility of existence of any finite counterexample.

I don't even understand such statement. First of all, in the first order logic the statements $\forall_x P(x)$ and $\neg\exists_x\neg P(x)$ are simply equivalent.
And then there's this "finite" word, which makes it even more mysterious. Are we supposed to interpret it as "but an infinite counterexample may exist"?  Which is just a meaningless mumbling.
I'm sorry, but that doesn't sound good at all.

One may say that they are exactly the same thing, but I've always felt that there is a subtle difference between showing something is true and showing something is not false.

There is no difference, at least not in the first order logic.
Some people do argue that proofs by contradiction are inferior, or even should be banned. But this isn't really about the difference between "true" and "not false", but more about constructing something vs showing it exists.
Regardless, "true" and "not false" remain the same in the first order logic, which is widely accepted as a standard mathematical logic. The same applies to "true for all" and "doesn't exist a counterexample". And in fact to higher order logics as well.
In other logic systems it depends. And it is a case-by-case study. But many will simply accept induction as an axiom, and typically in its "true" variant, not "not false" variant. To be honest, it is really weird for someone to think in "not false" manner, very unusual. Note that other logic systems are rather exotic in maths, compared to the first order logic.

no, "true" and "not false" are equivalent over classical logic. There are first-order versions of intuitionistic logic.

Let me be clearer. Whether or not "true" is equivalent to "not false" is a matter of whether we accept classical logic, or choose to work over intuitionistic logic. The adjective "first-order" is considered in opposition to, say, "propositional" logic. So there is first-order classical logic, first-order intuitionistic logic, classical propositional logic and intuitionistic propositional logic. So basically, if we accept the equivalence of "true" and "not false", we are working over classical logic. It is not the matter of debate here whether we are using first-order or propositional logic.

@ColinTan yes, every question is well defined in some language. Which is an irrelevant nitpicking. Just like the rest of your comments, even on my other questions. You must be very busy in life. XD

I am sorry, freakish. I shouldn't have been trying to shoot down your answer.

Also I've been taught that there is only one first order logic, well defined, with formal alphabet and rules. So I really don't know what "first order intuitionistic logic" is. But feel free to explain it in a separate answer.

First-order intuitionistic logic is first-order (classical) logic with some logical axioms removed. Offhand, I don't know exactly which axioms are removed. The axioms removed should ensure, for example, that the Law of Excluded Middle $\tau \vee \neg \tau$ is unprovable for any sentence $\tau$.

@ColinTan well it will always be provable for some sentence, for example those which you already proved were true

The truth-value of "showing something is true" and "showing something is not false" is just having "true" statements on one hand and "not yet proven nor disproven or undecidable" statements on the other hand. Mathematical induction, once completed, is not borderline but exact mathematics.
A famous quote on undecidable statements is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong .

I am only guessing here, but given that you mention "finite integers", perhaps your professor was thinking of hypernatural numbers, which are... if we simplify it a lot... infinite values "pretending to be" natural numbers.
I am not a professional mathematician, so I will probably use some wrong words here, but the general idea is that mathematicians are trying to prove things from axioms, and for some reason they prefer the axioms to be expressed in the language of predicate logic. The problem is that predicate logic is actually not sufficient to define natural numbers unambiguously.
We can choose a set of axioms (in predicate logic) that allows us to prove many statements about the natural numbers (but never all true statements; that's what Gödel's incompleteness theorem is about). These axioms are true about the natural numbers. Problem is, there are possible structures other than natural numbers that these axioms are also true about.
What do these other structures look like? They include all the natural numbers, plus some (infinitely many) extra values that "pretend to be" natural numbers, in the sense that if you take any of these "fake natural numbers", you can ask what is their successor, or you can do addition and multiplication with them, and the results are also within the same structure, and the operations on these values follow all the axioms that are true about the natural numbers.
Induction is typically defined as an infinite collection of axioms, one for each statement (in predicate logic) saying: "if this statement is true for zero, and if whenever it is true for n it is also true for n+1, then the statement is true for all natural numbers".
Now consider a statement "this is an actual natural number, not a fake one". It is true for zero. If it is true for n, it is also true for n+1. And yet... as I have said, there are structures containing extra values ("fake natural numbers"), about which all axioms (including the axioms of induction) are true. Wait... do we have a paradox here? How could a statement "this is not a fake natural number" be true about the "fake natural numbers"?
The answer is that there is no contradiction here; the induction axioms are only defined for statements that can be expressed using predicate logic. But "(not) a fake natural number" is something that cannot be expressed in predicate logic. The "fake natural numbers" are defined as those which the predicate logic cannot distinguish from the actual natural numbers.
Why did I call the "fake natural numbers" infinite, at the beginning of this answer? That's because you can keep subtracting one from them, forever, without even getting to zero. (If you keep subtracting one from a number, and then you get to zero, it was an actual natural number.) All the "fake natural numbers" are technically greater than all the actual natural numbers (a number is greater if you can subtract more ones from it), which matches our intuition of "infinity". But those numbers "pretend to be" natural, only... very big.
A professional mathematician could replace all the quote marks in this answer with some technical terms. But I hope it provides some insight this way, too.
